# Unity boolean variable needed in multiple scripts in different objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm recreating flappy bird to learn the basics of unity and C#, and a problem has popped up with no clear answer that I could find.

I have multiple scripts, but the important part is I have a boolean variable called birdalive. It is defined in the script called birdmove as follows:

```
public bool birdalive = true
```

I need to use this in a different script called space. This script is used to detect when the bird has gone through it. I now need to set up an if statement to check that the bird is not dead. This way if the bird dies on top of the bottom pipe before moving through it, it won't get the extra point for moving through that pipe. (for context, the level continues to move after you die, so the bird keeps sliding through)

This should be laid out as follows:

```
 private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (birdalive == true)
    {
        logic.addscore();
    }
}
```

but of course, I have an error message at the moment saying "the name 'birdalive' does not exist in the current context"

I know this is happening because birdalive has not been referenced properly in the space script, but I have no idea how to.

How do I make it so that the value of birdalive can be changed and read from (or in other words accessed in) both the space and the birdmove script?

Thanks :)

Comment: if a variable is public you can read and write to it, if a property is made you can maybe read and not write or write but not read (if you so need) or both read and write but also perform actions when it changes, if a singleton is made you can pickup the instance of your 1 bird and not worry about how or where it is because you can reference it anywhere, and any public properties within/

Comment: You could use delegates/events to subscribe to a 'bird crash' event from other scripts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates

Comment: @BugFinder Just wondering if you could elaborate, where in the script would I add the singleton, and is there an example you can give to help me put it together? Thanks

Comment: to make a singleton you add a public static variable of the class to itsself, and in its constructor or in our case start check if its the only one if the instance is already set it dies, if not it is set to be the instance.  Therefore you can now reference that.  Google has a lot of info and will give you a far fuller answer with examples

Answer (score 0):

Since you are learning the basics of unity and C#  I made a solution for you that makes since but this practice is not the best you don't want to make   **Interdependent Code**
(Look what Unity Design Patterns are they will help you to achieve  a better clean code)

**Solution 1**

In this script we want to reference our script that has this our birdalive bool like  this

```
    // Add this inside your space class
    public TheScriptThatHasYourBoolean bird;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (bird.birdalive == true)
        {
            logic.addscore();
        }
    }
```

Now after editing your code go to the editor and click on your space gameobject(s) and drag the bird (The game object that has the bool) inside the field

**Solution 2 singleton**
using
In the script that has birdalive boolean lets say its called Bird

```
public class Bird : MonoBehaviour
{

   public static Bird instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
       if(instance != null){

       Destroy(gameObject);

       }
       else
       {

         instance = this;
  
       }
    }
}
```

Then in your space script you can do this without the need to reference your script

```
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (Bird.instance.birdalive)
        {
            logic.addscore();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I want to say a huge thanks for helping me out! But I was just wondering, what would be the keywords I need to look up if I want to revisit this a year down the line for the "better solution" you mentioned, for when I'm much more confident? Many thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, just need to check something else about this solution: which field am I adding the bird game object to. I tried dragging it to the script, but that didn't work and I'm a little unsure now. Thanks again!

Comment: Your bird gameObject needs to have the script that has the boolean attached to it (as a component ) then you click on your space gameObjects(s) and drag your bird from the The Hierarchy window to the field in the inspector called bird